# A large percentage of unused space in the table

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2005.

I have a table size 16GB.  Table has 14 GB of free space.

```
sp_spaceused 'FREECLIENTDOC'

name            rows   reserved      data          index_size  unused
--------------- ------ ------------- ------------- ----------- ------------
FREECLIENTDOC   72407  16168232 KB   1742544 KB    30696 KB    14394992 KB
```

Indexes do not take up much space:

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning 'FREECLIENTDOC' table...
Table: 'FREECLIENTDOC' (659533433); index ID: 1, database ID: 7
TABLE level scan performed.
- Pages Scanned................................: 3508
- Extents Scanned..............................: 457
- Extent Switches..............................: 2555
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 7.7
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 17.18% [439:2556]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 71.18%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 69.80%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 1981.6
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 75.52%
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Perhaps the problem in the fields of image types.
How to determine what is in an unused space?
I'm interested in the general case definition table space. 
This table - a example.

Comment: Found an interesting effect. I did export to another DB, the new DB sp_spaceused showed data = 16312992 KB unused = 88 KB. 
Thus large unused in sp_spaceused is a bug in determining the size. 
Thank you to everyone who helped. 
But the question is, how did count correctly table size, remained open.

Answer (score 3):

If you have deleted a lot of data, this isn't recovered until you rebuild.

```
ALTER INDEX PK_PrimaryKeyName ON dbo.FREECLIENTDOC REBUILD;
```

Please see all the options [in the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388%28sql.90%29.aspx) before just running the default.

Also, `IMAGE` is deprecated - if you are storing files in your database tables, you should look into `VARBINARY(MAX)` - on newer versions of SQL Server you can look at FILESTREAM or FILETABLE.

Comment: If the problem was with the index, it would be seen in DBCC SHOWCONTIG. Image is not my choice, it is a choice vendor.

Comment: @Arty I don't know why you expect to find a "problem" anywhere - where did I suggest this was a problem? This is just how SQL Server works. If you want the space back, you need to ask for it.

Comment: Also a possibility, but probably more rare, is the case where you have dropped a column or increased the length of a column.  The space used by the dropped column is not reclaimed for the drop and a new column behind the scenes when you increase the column length.  Altering the index should reclaim that space.